# Android SQLite: Running the Same Query with Different Parameters Multiple Times Efficiently

Tags: java, android, database, performance, sqlite

I have a table in my `SQLite` database:

**Species**:

```
_id  |  species  |  description 
---------------------------
  1  |  Aardvark |  Some description for Aardvark
  2  |  Aardwolf |  Some description for Aardwolf
  3  |  Caracal  |  Some description for Caracal
```

I receive a list of ids from the server and I want to display only the species corresponding to the ids I received.

Now I am aware of a few options:

**1**. The obvious and naive way of doing this is something along the lines of:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.openDatabase();
for (int id : idList) {
    Cursor cursorSpecies = db.query(true, TABLE_SPECIES, new String[] {COL_SPECIES_SPECIES},
            COL_ID + "=?", id, null, null, null, null);
    cursorSpecies.moveToNext();
    speciesList.add(cursorSpecies.getString(0));
    cursorSpecies.close();
}
```

This will execute way too many operations and I assume multiple small "disk" reads, which would be very slow.

**2**. Another option would be to use an [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) but this only returns a single value, which doesn't work for my example and [shouldn't really be used for queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29797229) anyway.

**3**. Yet another option would be to manually concatenate the conditions into a raw `SQL` query, something along the lines of:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.openDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SPECIES + " WHERE ";
for (int id : idList) {
    query += COL_ID + "=" + id + " OR ";
}
// I am aware this will end in an " OR" but this is not the point of this example so please ignore it.
Cursor cursorSpecies  = db.rawQuery(query, null);
// Use the cursor and close it.

While this should work decently well, a very large query would probably break some query string length limit so this is not ideal either.
```

All of these examples would work to a certain extent but they all have pitfalls. Somehow I feel that I am missing a solution to this, hence the question:

**What is the proper way of executing this type of query?**

Thank you.

Comment: insert `idList` into some temp table and join ...

Comment: also `COL_ID = 1 OR COL_ID = 2 ... OR COL_ID = n` can simply  be `COL_ID IN(1,2, ..., n)`

Comment: I agree with laalto's answer, but I predict that when you measure your program, you will find that **1.** does not have any *noticeable* overhead. (Use a single transaction around all queries.)

Answer (score 1):

For the special case in the question, consider just `WHERE id IN (x,y,z, ...)`.

To address the question in the title and not just the special case in the question body:

The Android SQLite API is not very versatile in this regard.

In raw sqlite3 C API one would do it with a single `sqlite3_prepare*()` call to obtain a `sqlite3_statement` and bind the arguments in place, `sqlite3_step()` to get row(s) and then reset the statement to reuse it with new argument bindings.

In Android API, the statement corresponds to a `Cursor` and stepping is equivalent of moving the cursor. The reset and rebind functionality is only available in [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) as `requery()` and `setSelectionArguments()`.

So try something along the following lines:

1. Do a regular query with selection args.
2. Assuming the default cursor factory, cast the resulting `Cursor` to a `SQLiteCursor`.
3. Access the row(s) you need.
4. Update the selection args with `setSelectionArgs()`
5. `requery()`
6. Goto 3 unless done

Comment: It's worth noting that `WHERE id IN (a1,a2,a3, ...)` is limited to 999 a's in SQLite. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313495/5096103