# Room delete multiple rows by WHERE IN clause not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to delete multiple rows by their IDs in Android Room by `DELETE FROM...WHERE...IN (...)` clause. Below is the code:

ItemDao

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Item WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    fun deleteItemByIds(ids: String)
}
```

ItemViewModel

```
class ItemViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun deleteByIds(ids: String) {
        mScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mItemDao.deleteItemByIds(ids)
        }
    }
}
```

ItemActivity

```
fun onDelete(){
    // these are not real IDs, just for demo
    val itemIdList = arrayListOf<Long>(1, 2, 3)
    val ids = itemIdList.toString().drop(1).dropLast(1) // ids = "1, 2, 3"
    itemViewModel.deleteByIds(ids)
}
```

When there's only one ID, the code works. But when there are multiple IDs, it doesn't. So what happened here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to pass an array or list when you are dealing with `WHERE IN` clause. Like:

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Item WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    fun deleteItemByIds(ids: Array<Long>)
}
```

Comment: I changed the type to `Array<Long>` since the id type is `Long` and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TwistedLullaby you're welcome. Feel free to update the answer with your working code in case someone needs it.

Comment: Can you tell me what could be the maximum length of that list or where can I find out about this, any docs mentioning the limits? I'm getting an error.

Comment: @Vijay The limit is hardcoded in `sqlite.c` file, learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313495/4399414). What you should do is to split your array or list into smaller chunks below the limit and execute the query multiple times to achieve a complete deletion.

Comment: Instead of passing the ArrayList of ids now I passing ArrayList of the object itself and then annotating it with simple @Delete. This worked for me even for more than 10k deletion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question asks for deleting the rows with a list of Ids but my app crashes when I'm passing 10k+ Ids.
So instead I tried passing the object itself and it worked for me.

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {

    @Delete
    fun deleteUserByList(userList: Array<User>)

}
```

This way I'm able to delete more than 10k rows.

In case anyone needs it.

Comment: Basically, I agree with you. But the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar problem with RoomDatabase delete qwery. The problem was solved by apply of array type as a @Query function argument, but no list or string.

**IT IS NOT WORKING:**

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Item WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    fun deleteItemByIds(ids: List<Long>)
}
```

**OR:**

```
@Dao
    interface ItemDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Item WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    fun deleteItemByIds(ids: String)
}
```

**IT IS WORKING:**

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Item WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    fun deleteItemByIds(ids: LongArray)
}
```